# distutils does not install package_data on windows

Tags: python, windows, distutils

i've got the following line in my `setup.py` for one of my projects (full
script at bottom of question):

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup

# ...

setup(
    # ...
    package_data={
        'mesh.binding': ['templates/*'],
        'mesh.documentation': ['templates/*'],
    },
    # ...
)
```

this installs the contents of `mesh/binding/templates` to the
`site-packages/mesh/binding/templates` directory on Linux and OS X, but does
not succeed on windows.  **how do i get this to work on windows?**

i'm new to `distutils`, so forgive me if i'm forgetting something important.
i'm using `setuptools 0.6` and `python 2.7`.

### pertinent files

#### `setup.py`:

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup

version = '1.0.0'
try:
    revision = os.environ['REVISION']
except Exception:
    pass
else:
    version = revision

packages = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('mesh'):
    if '__init__.py' in files:
        packages.append(root.replace('/', '.'))

setup(
    name='mesh',
    version=version,
    description='A declarative RESTful API framework.',
    author='Jordan McCoy',
    author_email='mccoy.jordan@gmail.com',
    license='BSD',
    url='http://github.com/siq/mesh',
    packages=packages,
    package_data={
        'mesh.binding': ['templates/*'],
        'mesh.documentation': ['templates/*'],
    },
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Code Generators',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Application Frameworks',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    ]
)
```

#### `MANIFEST.in`:

```
recursive-include mesh/binding/templates *.tmpl
recursive-include mesh/documentation/templates *.tmpl
include LICENSE
include requirements.txt
include *.rst
recursive-include tests *.py
recursive-include examples *.rst *.py
include docs/conf.py docs/Makefile
recursive-include docs *.rst
recursive-include docs/_static *.css
recursive-include docs/_templates *.html
```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution i've found is just adding an extra step in my build.... which is a bummer, but i don't know of another way around it.

Comment: what is exact step?